# Additional bounding box appearing on output window

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The issue regarding the output is the occurrence of an additional bounding box excluding the recognized object. I basically tried upon the default data set provided by google but still i didn't get the expected result.

I'm running Tensorflow-13.1.0 on CPU and using Ubunutu 19.04. I really tried figuring out the visulatization_utils.py but no effect.

I need to know where to change the code so i don't get an additional box even before showing the object.

Comment: Can you show the code and the "additional bounding box"?

Comment: https://ibb.co/g4mqHyc - The output. Here if you can see actual image is indeed being detected but why am i getting the other box. It's same for all the images.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94635258742091266217 - Here's the config code.

Comment: Please add it to the post as text/image. Never put download links. :-)

Comment: How do i add? I can't see any options of attachement. Besides I'm a newbie to this forum. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't attach files on StackOverflow. Instead use the "Code Sample" to insert the essential code to reproduce your problem. Try reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay so what code are we talking about? let me tell you the parameters you need.

Comment: First : I've set num_classes: 1 (only one ID used in annotation tool). num_steps : 1000. Avg loss rate : 1.3405 (3.2 sec/stop) num_examples : 20 . I guess i need to modify the visualtization_utils.py. And the output is ineed an image so i cannot post here right.

Comment: First, Welcome to Stackoverflow! :-) But you need to add all this information to your post by clicking [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56407077/edit) and adding it there. Other people may come here with the same problem, and they should be able to understand your problem from the text, not the comments.

Comment: Is there any way we could help out in another manner? I'm really stuck at this part. I've tried everything but my last place was stackoverflow. I need to get used to this.

Comment: You can upload it to github and post a link, then I'll add it to your post.

Comment: I've found the answer. Thank you for the concern. It was the issue of re-training the same images time after time repeatedly.

Comment: Great! Consider updating your post with the necessary information and answer your question with the fix. This way, others with similar problems may benefit from this thread.